# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: hobbies is not iterable at createHobby when using Prisma and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

So I'm very new to Prisma, and actually also to React. My Postgresql database works, but I'm trying to show the stored data in my application. My very simple table in the schema file looks like this:

```
model Hobby {
  id        Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
}
```

I'm using `useContext` to distribute my `createHobby` functionality, this is what the context file looks like.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const hobbies: Prisma.HobbyUncheckedCreateInput[] = await prisma.hobby.findMany();
    return {
        props: {initialHobbies: hobbies},
    };
}

export const HobbyContext = createContext({})
function Provider({ children, initialHobbies }){

    const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useState<Prisma.HobbyUncheckedCreateInput[]>(initialHobbies);

    const createHobby = async (title) => {

        const body: Prisma.HobbyCreateInput = {
            title,

        };
        await fetcher("/api/create-hobby", {hobby : body});
        console.log(hobbies);

        const updatedHobbies = [
            ...hobbies,
            body
        ];
        setHobbies(updatedHobbies);

    const contextData = {
        hobbies,
        createHobby,

    }
    return (
        <HobbyContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {children}
        </HobbyContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default HobbyContext;
export {Provider};
```

Here I get the following error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: hobbies is not iterable at createHobby`. Which refers to the `const updatedHobbies = [...hobbies, body];`

For more context, I have a `HobbyCreate.tsx` which creates a little hobby card that renders the title of the hobby, which is submitted with a form.

```
function HobbyCreate({updateModalState}) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const {createHobby} = useHobbiesContext();
    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value)
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        createHobby(title);
    };
    return (
        ...
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
        ...


    )
```

I can't really figure out what is going wrong, I assume somewhere when creating the `const [hobbies, setHobbies]` and using the initialHobbies.

Comment: that's because ...hobbies assume that hobbies is an array type. Which it isn't in this code

Comment: @Kwright02 I see what you mean, but for example with this `const [users, setUsers] = useState<Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateInput[]>(initialUsers)` and `await setUsers([...users, body]);` it works fine.

Comment: That's because the users param is expected to be an array

Comment: @Kwright02 They look the same to me, but maybe I'm missing something. Any tips on how I can adjust that?

Comment: Not sure if you only included it here for completeness, but `getServerSideProps` can only be used on a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) correctly. I've written working code to try and show you how to use it.

#### Fully typed hobby provider implementation

This is a fully typed implementation of your `Provider`:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import type { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
import fetcher from 'path/to/fetcher';

export type HobbyContextData = {
  hobbies: Prisma.HobbyCreateInput[]
  createHobby: (title: string) => void
};

// you could provide a meaningful default value here (instead of {})
const HobbyContext = createContext<HobbyContextData>({} as any);

export type HobbyProviderProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  initialHobbies: Prisma.HobbyCreateInput[]
}>;

function HobbyProvider({ initialHobbies, children }: HobbyProviderProps) {
  const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useState<Prisma.HobbyCreateInput[]>(initialHobbies);

  const createHobby = async (title: string) => {
    const newHobby: Prisma.HobbyCreateInput = {
      title,
    };

    await fetcher("/api/create-hobby", { hobby: newHobby });

    console.log(hobbies);

    setHobbies((hobbies) => ([
      ...hobbies,
      newHobby,
    ]));
  };

  const contextData: HobbyContextData = {
    hobbies,
    createHobby,
  };

  return (
    <HobbyContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {children}
    </HobbyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default HobbyContext;
export { HobbyProvider };
```

### Using `HobbyProvider`

You can use `HobbyProvider` to provide access to `HobbyContext` for every component wrapped inside it.
For example, to use it in every component on `/pages/hobbies` your implementation would look like:

```
// /pages/hobbies.tsx
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import HobbyContext, { HobbyProvider } from 'path/to/hobbycontext';

export default function HobbiesPage() {
  // wrapping the entire page in the `HobbyProvider`
  return (
    <HobbyProvider initialHobbies={[{ title: 'example hobby' }]}>
      <ExampleComponent />
      {/* page content */}
    </HobbyProvider>
  );
}

function ExampleComponent() {
  const { hobbies, createHobby } = useContext(HobbyContext);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      hobbies: {JSON.stringify(hobbies)}
      <div>
        <input
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => createHobby(title)}>Create hobby</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Similarly, to make the context available throughout your entire website, you can use `HobbyProvider` in
[`/pages/_app.tsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

#### Using `getServerSideProps`

To retrieve the `initialHobbies` from the database, your `getServerSideProps` would look something like this:

```
// /pages/hobbies.tsx
import type { Hobby } from '@prisma/client';

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // note: there is no need to use `Hobby[]` as prisma will automatically give you the correct return
  // type depending on your query
  const initialHobbies: Hobby[] = await prisma.hobby.findMany();

  return {
    props: {
      initialHobbies,
    },
  };
}
```

You would have to update your page component to receive the props from `getServerSideProps` and set `initialHobbies` on `HobbyProvider`:

```
// /pages/hobbies.tsx
import type { InferGetServerSidePropsType } from 'next';

export default function HobbiesPage({ initialHobbies }: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  return (
    <HobbyProvider initialHobbies={initialHobbies}>
      <ExampleComponent />
    </HobbyProvider>
  );
}
```

> Note your page component and `getServerSideProps` function have to be exported from the same file